# Accommodation details for booked tour while applying for a visa

Tags: visas, schengen, tours

I have booked a tour for my travel to Iceland and accommodation is included in it, but I have not yet received details of accommodation. In order to apply for a visa will the tour itinerary along with proof of booked tour be sufficient?

On the VFS website it simply says this:

> Proof of accommodation: Hotel bookings or accommodation guarantees covering the whole duration of the intended stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called up VFS office and they said that accommodation must be proven in documents.
Then i checked out with Tour operator and as tour is far away they were not of much help.
So in the end, i decided not to show tour as part of application and instead booked accommodation and provided its details as part of my application.

I got my Visa without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to apply for a visa will the tour itinerary along with proof of booked tour be sufficient?

Since your booked tour contains accommodation, this will certainly be adequate. Just that your tour confirmation document needs to clearly mention the fact.

Which exact address do they provide you that accommodation at is not critically important when the whole package is booked as a tour.